# Import global variable with latest assigned value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to import global variable from one file to another. Though the value of variable is changed at multiple location and i need to import latest value that global variable carries.

```
file_One.py:
a = "Old Value"

def some_somefunction():
  global a
  a = "New Value"
```

Now I need the global variable with value "New Value" to be imported.

```
file_two.py:
import file_One

print file_One.a
```

o/p

> Old value

Is there a way i can import global variable a with "New Value"?

Comment: The global variable does not have the value "New Value" until you actually call the function.

Comment: Yes, and don't use global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_One.a` will work just fine. You didn't run `some_somefunction`, so the value hasn't actually changed. (Note that `from file_One import a` will not work.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get "New Value" in **file_two.py** you need to `from file_One import some_somefunction` & then call the function some_somefunction() or you can simply print some_somefunction() after you import it, also you need to `return` the value in def 
a quick example:

**file_One.py:**

```
def some_somefunction():
    a = "New Value"
    return a
```

**file_two.py**

```
from file_One import some_somefunction

print some_somefunction()
```